# ORA 12154 - TNS Error from API deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

We deployed our .Net core api in Kubernetes.Our container is up and running. When the request is about connect to oracle db we get an exception that “ TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified “

Connection string is coded in appsettings..json file and we have passed this file during build stage in docker file.

How to resolve this.

Comment: Could you please share some more information - how exactly did you setup this app, do you have some logs (for example from the pod)? Could you share YAML files used for this deployment, also the `appsettings.json` file and Docker File? Please make [your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Initially provided DB name and credentials to the connection string. Tried adding Oracle server IP and Port Number to the connection String and my issue got resolved.